# while loop in C# with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, .net, while-loop, conditional-statements

This is my code:

```
while( Func(x) != ERR_D)
{
   if(result == ERR_A) 
         throw...; 
   if(result == ERR_B)
         throw...;

  mydata.x = x;
 }
```

The problem is that I want to use `result = Func(x)` in the while condition as the result will be checked inside the while loop. The while loop should call `Func(x)` untill it returns `ERR_D`.
I can't use

```
do{ 
    result = Func(x);
   if(result == ERR_A) 
         throw ...; 
   if(result == ERR_B)
         throw ...;
    mydata.x = x;
   }while(result != ERR_D);
```

in my project as it first calls `Func(x)` which is what I don't want. 
But I have tried `while(result = Func(x) != ERR_D)`, it doesn't work. Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Well, `x` never changes. Maybe that has something to do with it? Hard to say, since "doesn't work" could mean almost anything and we have no idea what's supposed to be happening.

Comment: `var result = Func(x); while (result != ERR_D) { doStuff(); result = Func(x); }`?

Comment: Does it really make sense to throw exceptions in a while-loop? the loop will terminate as soon as one is thrown...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to add some parentheses:

```
while((result = Func(x)) != ERR_D) { /* ... */ }
```

The `!=` operator has a higher priority than the assignment, so you need to force the compiler to perform the assignment first (which evaluates to the assigned value in C#), before comparing the values on both sides of the `!=` operator with each other. That's a pattern you see quite often, for example to read a file:

```
string line;

while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try declaring `result` outside the loop and then assign it `Funcs` return value on each iteration.

For instance:

```
var result = Func(x);

while(result != ERR_D)
{
   if(result == ERR_A) 
         throw...; 
   if(result == ERR_B)
         throw...;

  mydata.x = x;
  result = Func(x);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
while((result=Func(x)) != ERR_D){
 if(result == ERR_A) 
      throw...; 
 if(result == ERR_B)
      throw...;
 mydata.x = x;
}
```

**NOTE**: the assignment is done first in the parenthesis `(result=Func(x))`, this assignment is in fact done by the overload of the operator `=` and this operator returns the reference to the left side operand, that is `result`. After that, the `result` will be compared against the `ERR_D` via the operator `!=`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
while((result = Func(x)) != ERR_D)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could express this using a `while (true)...`:

```
while (true)
{
    var result = Func(x);

    if (result == ERR_D)
        break;

    if (result == ERR_A) 
        throw ...; 

    if (result == ERR_B)
        throw ...;

    mydata.x = x;            
}
```

This is a loop-with-one-exit (if you ignore the throws ;)) so it is a structured loop.

You could also use a `for` loop, although it looks a little funky (pun not intended!):

```
for (var result = Func(x); result != ERR_D; result = Func(x))
{
    if (result == ERR_A) 
        throw ...; 

    if (result == ERR_B)
        throw ...;

    mydata.x = x;     
}
```